# How can I control form submit remote with variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to control when to refresh page (respond_to format.html) and when to toggle buttons (respond_to format.js), by passing local variable to partial used for remote: true (remote: remote_flag), but that variable remote_flag is always false.

------------- parent partial ----------------

```
<% if current_user.following?(user_event) %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/remove_favorite', 
    locals: { user_event: user_event, remote_flag: true } %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/add_favorite', 
    locals: { user_event: user_event, remote_flag: true } %>
<% end %>
```

------------- add favorite partial ----------------

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favorites.build(followed_event_id: user_event.id), 
  html: { id: "event_number_#{user_event.id}" }, remote: remote_flag) do |f| %>
  <div class="hidden"><%= f.hidden_field :followed_event_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Add to favorites %>
<% end %>
```

------------- remove favorite partial ----------------

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favorites.find_by_followed_event_id(user_event),
  html: { id: "event_number_#{user_event.id}", method: :delete }, remote: remote_flag) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove from favorites %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`@remote_flag` is an instance variable, not the local variable, so it isn't passed to the partial with `locals: { user_event: user_event, remote_flag: false }` construction. Since it isn't set, it is (by default) `nil` and it behaves like `false` in conditional statements. Instead, you should rather use your passed local variable, `remote_flag`:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favorites.find_by_followed_event_id(user_event),
  html: { id: "event_number_#{user_event.id}", method: :delete }, remote: remote_flag) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove from favorites %>
<% end %>
```

and pass variable through `locals: {...}` construction or set an instance variable explicitly in controller:

```
@remote_flag = !!condition
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but still not working: <%= render partial: 'shared/remove_favorite', 
    locals: { user_event: user_event, remote_flag: true } %>           <%= form_for(current_user.favorites.find_by_followed_event_id(user_event),
  html: { id: "event_number_#{user_event.id}", method: :delete }, remote: remote_flag) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove from favorites", class: "info_inline_control info_button_small user_event_summary_item" %>
<% end %>

Comment: @GregLafrance What does it mean "it's not working"? Is it raising an error?

Comment: I'm setting remote_flag: true but in the partial remote: remote_flag still seems to be false, because it is redirecting. When I set remote_flag to true format_js should be used, and when remote_flag is false, then format.html should be used, for redirect.

Comment: @GregLafrance you can easily check whether the problem is badly generated form or other thing. Inspect your form with browser tool like `Firebug` and search for `remote="true"` flag. If it's there, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: _remove_favorite.html.erb line 2 is raising error "undefined local variable or method remote_flag", so @remote_flag doesn't work and remote_flag gives the error.

Comment: @GregLafrance Strange behaviour. Are you sure you rendered partial properly? No typos? Anyway, it should work with an instance variable set to true. So try to set instance variable to true and check if form in partial is rendered properly. If it is, check for possible javascript errors.

Comment: This code shows remote_flag local var exists and is set to true, because "here is rendered", but for some reason I can't access the var for remote:. <% if remote_flag %>
  <p>here</p>
<% end %>
<%= form_for(current_user.favorites.build(followed_event_id: user_event.id), 
  html: { id: "event_number_#{user_event.id}" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="hidden"><%= f.hidden_field :followed_event_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Add to favorites" %>
<% end %>

Comment: Does the remote action work if you explicitly pass `remote: true`?

Comment: It does work in that case. In fact, it works if I set remote: user_event.

Comment: I added info to the top of the question. I think I'm getting close.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I finally solved this one. Whew, lots of investigation, but I learned lots along the way. I'll share my solution here.

So my scenario is that I'm trying to be DRY, and so I have two partials for "Add to favorites" and "Remove from favorites" buttons. In my event management app, search results page shows events, and initially the "Add to favorites" button partial is rendered. When user clicks button, AJAX form submit replaces that partial with the "Remove from favorites" partial. That way user can toggle between adding to/removing from favorites if they change their mind.

But I also want to use those "Add to favorites" / "remove from favorites" partials on the user profile page, and favorites index page, and on those pages, when user clicks "Remove from favorites", I don't want the "Add to favorites" button to show up, I want to refresh the page so the list of favorites is minus that removed item. In this case, I simply don't do an AJAX call.

To achieve this I need a way to control the remote: for the form, true for the AJAX call, false for the HTML (page refresh) call. The following code (only what is relevant shown) is how I did it.

Hope this helps someone else.

----------------- parent partial -----------------

Here in the parent partial, setting remote_flag: true prevents page refresh through AJAX call, and remote_flag: false would be HTML call, for page refresh.

```
<% if current_user.following?(user_event) %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/remove_favorite', 
    locals: { user_event: user_event, remote_flag: true } %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/add_favorite', 
    locals: { user_event: user_event, remote_flag: true } %>
<% end %>
```

------------- add favorite partial ----------------

The hidden_field :remote_flag allows controller to access via params[:remote_flag].

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favorites.build(followed_event_id: user_event.id), 
  html: { id: "event_number_#{user_event.id}" }, remote: remote_flag) do |f| %>
  <div class="hidden"><%= f.hidden_field :followed_event_id %></div>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :remote_flag, value: remote_flag %>

  <%= f.submit "Add to favorites", 
    class: "info_button_small user_event_summary_item" %>
<% end %>
```

------------- remove favorite partial ----------------

The hidden_field :remote_flag allows controller to access via params[:remote_flag].

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favorites.find_by_followed_event_id(user_event),
  html: { id: "event_number_#{user_event.id}", method: :delete }, remote: remote_flag) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :remote_flag, value: remote_flag %>

  <%= f.submit "Remove from favorites", class: "info_inline_control info_button_small user_event_summary_item" %>
<% end %>
```

---------------- Favorites controller ----------------

In the controller, this code allows create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb to access @remote_flag:

```
@remote_flag = params[:remote_flag]


class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @remote_flag = params[:remote_flag]
    @user_event = UserEvent.find(params[:favorite][:followed_event_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user_event)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user) }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
  end

  def destroy
    @remote_flag = true
    @user_event = Favorite.find(params[:id]).followed_event
    current_user.unfollow!(@user_event)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user) }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

--------------- create.js.erb -------------------

```
<% if @current_user.following?(@user_event) %>
  $("#event_number_<%= @user_event.id %>").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render(
    partial: 'shared/remove_favorite', locals: { user_event: @user_event, remote_flag: @remote_flag })) %>');
<% end %>
```

--------------- destroy.js.erb -------------------

```
<% if !@current_user.following?(@user_event) %>
  $("#event_number_<%= @user_event.id %>").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render(
    partial: 'shared/add_favorite', locals: { user_event: @user_event, remote_flag: @remote_flag })) %>');
<% end %>
```