# Render Partial in Controller vs Render Partial in View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, controller, partial

Why I can render a partial from the js.erb file like this:

```
var codehtml = '<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/error_messages' )  %>';
```

but when I try to render_to_string it from a controller and pass it thru controller to the view like this:

```
@rendererrors = render_to_string( :partial => 'shared/error_messages' )
```

i get double quotes (or, i don't know, just wrongly escaped string) and it can't be interpreted as html?

Im trying to put it in my html code with this JS routine in .js.erb file:

```
var codehtml = '<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/error_messages' )  %>';
var ew = document.getElementById('errors');

ew.innerHTML = codehtml;
```

Comment: Why not using `@rendererrors = escape_javascript( render_to_string( :partial => 'shared/error_messages' ) )` in your controller? Or just render?

Comment: I did this in one of my questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420729/how-can-i-control-form-submit-remote-with-variable): `<% if @current_user.following?(@user_event) %>
  $("#event_number_<%= @user_event.id %>").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render(
    partial: 'shared/remove_favorite', locals: { user_event: @user_event, remote_flag: @remote_flag })) %>');
<% end %>`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, i was using it on controller but for some reason it was renderized in view between double quotes... even with escape_javascript as I explained in the question.